# Data from multiple worksheets starts to imput in the wrong cell of the mastersheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

first time asker here.
I found a nice VBA code to copy the same specific cells from multiple worksheets into a mastersheets and actually does its job (i don't remember where I founf it originally). The only small issue is that it starts to input the data from cell A2, while I would like it to start from cell A4.

Here is the code:

```
Sub ListFB()
Sheets("Master").Range("A4").Value = "Sheet Name"
For I = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
If Sheets(I).Name <> "RiassuntoTEST" Then
    Sheets("Master").Cells(I, 1).Value = Sheets(I).Range("B2").Value
   Sheets("Master").Cells(I, 2).Value = Sheets(I).Range("C2").Value
   Sheets("Master").Cells(I, 3).Value = Sheets(I).Range("C10").Value
   Sheets("Master").Cells(I, 4).Value = Sheets(I).Range("C11").Value
   Sheets("Master").Cells(I, 5).Value = Sheets(I).Range("C15").Value
   Sheets("Master").Cells(I, 6).Value = Sheets(I).Range("C16").Value
   Sheets("Master").Cells(I, 7).Value = Sheets(I).Range("C20").Value
   Sheets("Master").Cells(I, 8).Value = Sheets(I).Range("C21").Value
   Sheets("Master").Cells(I, 9).Value = Sheets(I).Range("C25").Value
   Sheets("Master").Cells(I, 10).Value = Sheets(I).Range("C26").Value
   Sheets("Master").Cells(I, 11).Value = Sheets(I).Range("C29").Value
   Sheets("Master").Cells(I, 12).Value = Sheets(I).Range("C30").Value
   Sheets("Master").Cells(I, 13).Value = Sheets(I).Range("C33").Value
   Sheets("Master").Cells(I, 14).Value = Sheets(I).Range("C34").Value
    End If
Next I
End Sub
```

What I think it does is take value B2 from Sheet I and copy it to A2 of the mastersheet, then take C2 and copy it to B2, until it has all the required data from that sheet into the same rows, then goes to the next sheet and puts the data in the next rows. As I said above, I would like that this whole process starts from A4 instead of A2.

I am fairly new to this kind of stuff so any input and help is appreciated.
Also, does the row

```
Sheets("Master").Range("A4").Value = "Sheet Name"
```

Do anything for my purpose at all?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue:

```
Sheets("RiassuntoTEST").Cells(I, 1).Value
```

`Cells` holds what is known as an `R1C1` reference. Meaning Row number, Column number. Since this line `I = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count` counts from 1 to the number of worksheets you have, this will start pasting in row 1, column 1, also known as cell `A1`. If you want to up this to cell A4 instead, you will need to increase this by 3 like so:

```
Sheets("RiassuntoTEST").Cells(I + 3, 1).Value
```

You will need to do this on every line.

Second issue:

> Also, does the row
>   Sheets("RiassuntoTEST").Range("A4").Value = "Nome Foglio"
>   Do anything for my purpose at all?

No, it does not, as stated before, your code will (now) start pasting at cell A4, so as soon as the second block starts running, this is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code in such a way as to enable you to make all the amendments you might want - perhaps with a little help from the comments I inserted between the lines of code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateMaster()
    ' Variatus @STO 23 Jan 2020

    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim MasterWs As Worksheet
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim SourceCell() As String
    Dim Rt As Long                          ' target row
    Dim Ct As Long                          ' target column
    Dim i As Integer

    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook                   ' you might specify another workbook
    ' specify the Master worksheet here
    Set MasterWs = Wb.Worksheets("TEST")
    ' list all the source cells here
    SourceCell = Split("B2,C2,C10,C11,C15,C16,C20,C21,C25,C26,C29,C30,C33,C34", ",")
    Rt = 4                                  ' set first row to write to here

    With MasterWs
        ' keep contents in rows 1 to 3 (incl title)
        .Range(.Cells(Rt, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp) _
                                     .Offset(0, UBound(SourceCell) + 1)) _
                                     .ClearContents
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False      ' speeds up execution
    For i = 1 To Wb.Worksheets.Count
        Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets(i)
        If Not Ws Is MasterWs Then
            For Ct = 0 To UBound(SourceCell)
                MasterWs.Cells(Rt + i - 1, Ct + 1) = Ws.Range(Trim(SourceCell(Ct))).Value
            Next Ct
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```